# Are the spaces of real orthogonal, complex unitary, hermitian or symmetric matrices connected?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, connectedness

I want to know which of these are connected and which are not. I think I've to take some continuous map from the set of matrices to $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ and interpret these matrix sets as inverse images of connected sets to conclude they are connected. What maps do I take? I don't think the determinant map works everywhere, if at all. Can anyone provide a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A continuous map is indeed helpful in proving a set is disconnected.  In fact, consider the determinant over the real orthogonal matrices.  What is the image of this map?  What can you conclude as a result?

Note that any path connected space is connected.  For the symmetric and Hermitian matrices, consider $p:[0,1] \to \Bbb C^{n \times n}$ given by 
$$
t \mapsto (1-t)A + tB
$$

All that's left now is the set of complex unitary matrices.  This set is also path connected, but there is a trickier path here.  Perhaps you can make sense of the map
$$
t \mapsto A^{(1-t)}B^t
$$
Alternatively, note that
$$
A \mapsto e^{iA}
$$
is a continuous onto map from the Hermitian matrices to the complex unitary matrices.

---

The matrix exponential is probably the quicker way to go here.  We define the exponential map by
$$
\exp(X) = e^X = I + X + \frac 1{2!} X^2 + \frac 1{3!} X^3 + \cdots
$$
We have the following properties: 
$$
\exp \pmatrix{d_1\\&\ddots \\ && d_n} = 
\pmatrix{e^{d_1} \\ & \ddots \\ && e^{d_n}}
$$
and for any invertible $S$ and matrix $A$, we have
$$
\exp(SAS^{-1}) = S \exp(A) S^{-1}
$$
Now, using the spectral theorem, show that if $A$ is Hermitian, then $\exp(iA)$ is unitary.

Comment: I guess I've to use properties of symmetric , Hermitian or unitary matrices to prove the continuity of the above maps. How do I do that?

Comment: You just need to use the definition of continuity with respect to one of the usual metrics on $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$.

Comment: I get it, but can't make sense of the path you've given for the unitary case. And the alternative approach involves raising $e$ to some complex power involving a matrix-something I've not seen before. can you explain a bit more?

Comment: See my latest edit.  Whichever method you choose, the spectral theorem is necessary at some point.

Comment: Got it, thanks.